# per-charge cost to charge a battery bank at $0.10/kwhr

Tags: power, batteries

Am I forgetting my EE knowledge?

I have a 10400mAh battery bank at 3.8v so it's ~40kwhr?

$4 to charge once? assuming perfect charger efficiency and no power loss to heat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just your SI prefixes.  10.4 Ah * 3.8 v = 40 Wh = 0.04 kWh = $0.004.

Comment: I think that's probably even worse!!! :( heh.... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1: Yes.

2: How can we possibly know whether the battery bank you describe is indeed what you have!?

3: No.

First, it helps to use proper engineering units.  Too many digits makes things confusing, as apparently happened here.  "10400 mAh" is 10.4 Ah in grown-up units.  Assuming ideal battery and power supply just to get a starting point, that's 10.4 A for one hour to charge.  (10.4 A)(3.8 V) = 40 W.  That times 1 hour = 40 Wh.  You pay $.10 per kWh, or $0.0001 per Wh.  That times the 40 Wh you will use costs $0.004, or 4/10 of one cent.

In reality charging such a battery will take substantially more energy than what you get by assuming everything is ideal.  Figuring 1 cent ($.01) should be conservative enough.

Comment: 2-- this can be calculated-- 10.4*3.8 is 39.5watt-hours. But yes, it was the units. Thanks for correcting my dumbass mistake ;) I should know better...regarding 'substantially more energy', why is that? I've understood batteries to charge at ~80% efficiency rule-of-thumb (at least that's what it is for the Teslas)-- why 'substantially more'?

Comment: @peda: 80% quite high for ordinary rechargeable batteries.  Tesla used the right kind of batteries and probably spent a lot of engineering effort getting every last bit of efficiency from the system.  You also have to consider the efficiency of the power supplies to charge the battery from wall power, and possibly to deliver the power to the load during discharge.  Two 90% power supplies gets you to 81% overall before even considering the battery efficiency.